# macOS terminal, directory of the User folder

Tags: macos, terminal

I know the question sounds banal, but I've searched everywhere throughout the internet and using the terminal. So here it is. How to find the **User** folder directory on macOS using the Terminal?

I think it would be useful to also see the hidden files in the terminal, but I could not find the answer to that question either.

Thank you.

Comment: What is "the User directory"? What have you tried to find it? And is this in any way related to programming (otherwise, this would be off-topic here)

Comment: I am trying to get to the .ssh folder in order to add a config file with some configuration so I believe it is related to programming. Not sure how to explain more precisely the directory **User**. Folder **User** on my Macbook? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please share more details, like your attempts to find that folder. Is that the folder of the currently logged in user? The folder of any other, specific user?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the folder of the currently logged-in user (jgaw). I've searched throughout the folders such as Desktop Downloads Movies Pictures Documents Library Music Public. These are the only folders I can see in my Terminal when typing the "ls" command line. When searching in **Finder**, I can see: **jgaw(MeAsUser)/.shh**. But when using Terminal, I have no idea how to locate that folder.

Comment: Have you tried using `ls -a`? Usually, `ls` hides folders starting with a dot

Comment: That is the answer that helped me understand the issue. I’m currently on that directory (folder) of the User (jgaw). Now I can see it clearly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Danke Schön Nico Haase for the help.
By default, when opening the Terminal, you are in the current User's directory.
If you are looking for some hidden files, please use the command **ls -a** so You can see them clearly.